# Pytesseract - output is extremely inaccurate (MAC)

Tags: python, text, python-tesseract

I installed pytesseract via pip and its result is terrible.

As I searched for it, I think I need to give it more data
but I can't find where to put tessedata(traineddata)
since there is no directory like ProgramFile\Tesseract-OCR using Mac.

There is no problem with images' resolution, font or size.
[Image whose result is 'ecient Sh Abu'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Celp.jpg)

Because large and clear test images work fine, I think it is a problem about lack of data.
But any other possible solution is welcomed as long as it can read text with Python.

Please help me..

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "runs really poor?" It sounds like you're not getting the correct results, and you're not sure where to put the training data?

Comment: That's what I exactly meant. Even if I put a large enough and clear image, it doesn't recognize it properly. Since I found no answer for my problem during hours of searching but putting data, I questioned where should I put data but I'm not sure what's the reason for this. And thank you for trying to help me, sorry for my poor English..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I installed pytesseract via pip and its result is terrible.

Sometimes you need to apply preprocessing to the input image to get accurate results.

> Because large and clear test images work fine, I think it is a problem about lack of data. But any other possible solution is welcomed as long as it can read text with Python.

You could say lack of data is a problem. I think you'll find [morphological-transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) useful.

For instance if we apply `close` operation, the result will be:

[image]

The image looks similar to the original posted image. However there are slight changes in the output images (i.e. Grammar word is slightly different from the original image)

Now if we read the output image:

```
English
Grammar Practice
ter K-SAT (1-10)
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("6Celp.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
opn = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, None)
txt = image_to_string(opn)
txt = txt.split("\n")
for i in txt:
    i = i.strip()
    if i != '' and len(i) > 3:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Windowsill make sure to search image skewing and correction if you are working with the rotated images.